# value propagation in a std::vector

Tags: c++

If I have a `std::vector` initialized like this:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5
```

how can I best propagate the 4 to the first place? I.e. I want the `std::vector` in this state:

```
4 0 1 2 3 5
```

Removing the 4 and reinserting it could be expensive, as insertions at the front are `O(N)`, I believe. I was thinking about swapping values in successive places (like in bubble sort), but that would be also `O(N)`. Is using another container, like `std::list` the only way?

EDIT:
After seeing some confusion, let me clarify, that my objective is to prepend a value at a known arbitrary location in the `std::vector` in front of a value at another known location in the `std::vector`.

Comment: You still need `O(N)` to find `4` in `std::list`.

Comment: Assume I know where the `4` is. Finding is not an issue here.

Comment: Why are you moving the 4 to the front? Different contexts can suggest very different solutions.

Comment: Create a new vector, put the `4` in front and the rest after it, then assign the new vector to the old. With C++11 move semantics it should hopefully not be as expensive as it sound.

Comment: I must prepend a value at a known location in front of value at another known location.

Comment: If you're doing this operation frequently, I suggest using std::deque, which is optimized for inserting at the front.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg "create a new vector and put something in it" sounds like a memory allocation for the new vector, with and without move semantics.

Comment: Obviously if you want to stick to a vector, this operation will require `O(N)` because you need to modify `O(N)` values. Linked list would work if you somehow have the pointers to the two elements.

Comment: @Alex: you can't remove an element from the middle of a deque, though.

Comment: 4 1 2 3 0 5 is not the desired output

Comment: @riv Exactly, both locations can be arbitrary.

Comment: @riv, What about `erase`?

Comment: @ArneMertz Well, the size is already known, so only one allocation is needed. It's worth testing at least.

Comment: @user1095108: You're just restating the question. Why do you need to rearrange elements? What's the bigger problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @riv: You're right. You could use deque::erase, but of course that's still O(n). But I reckon erasing a certain element in a list would still be O(n), since you need to traverse through the list to find that element.

Comment: @chris: deque might be optimized for inserting/removing elements at either end, but removing a random element would most likely take `O(n)` time, which destroys the point.

Comment: @Alex: sure, the only way to get anything lower would be using a list *and* somehow having the pointer to the required value beforehand.

Comment: IMO, doing such operation in `O(N)` is pretty good. But if you want to do it `N` times, there are bigger chance to compress `O(N*N)` to lower.

Comment: @riv, I was merely saying that you can, not that it's a particularly good idea here. The comment seemed to suggest it wasn't possible.

Comment: you could write a comparator that makes 4 smaller than everything and use it in std::sort. Or do some std::swap of elements until they are in the order you like.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: unless the author prefers `O(n log n)` to `O(n)` for some reason, that doesn't seem to be a very good idea.

Comment: `std::list` is better if you insert/remove from the middle orders of magnitude more often than you iterate through the container.  So it really matters *how* you know where `4` is: if you walked the container to find `4`, and now want to move it to the front, optimizing the move-to-front by using a `list` will cost you more time in the walking than you gain in the moving!  There are cases where `std::list` is the right answer, but it requires knowing the entire life cycle of the container to determine if this is such a case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Changing the container (e.g. std::deque) is the only option if O(N) is an issue.

However, do make sure that O(N) really is an issue!

Comment: And how would you do it in less than O(N) with an `std::list`? You need to find the element with value equal to `4` first.

Comment: you are right, I was thinking about std::deque. Thanks for pointing that out. The question author says "finding" is not an issue (e.g. he can already have an iterator to the element)

Comment: @StefanoFalasca Yes, I know both the "source" and "destination" locations.

Comment: @user1095108 Though a *"location"* (which could mean "index", "value" or whatever) might not neccessarily be an *"iterator"* (as needed for `erase`). And getting one from the other might not be that easy (say O(1)) for a `std::list`. That's the whole point of *juanchopanza*'s comment. Even if you got an index and not just a value *that is not enough* (though nobody says you cannot change your computation from index-based to iterator-based in case of a list, but by all means don't use a `std::list` just because of big-O, which is rarely ever a valid reason in practice).

Comment: Using `std::deque` will still yield `O(N)` due to `erase`.

Comment: it will not, erase is "Linear on the number of elements erased"

Comment: `std::deque` is O(N) in the described operation.

Comment: `std::deque` can erase at O(1) time from the beginning or end, but any other position is O(N). The `deque` is composed of a series of arrays. The only container that allows such rearrangement is `list`, and finding 4 isn't part of the problem as stated. (Finding can be done faster than O(N) if the sequence is sorted, which the example one is, but the general guarantee wasn't mentioned.)

Comment: std::deque::erase documentation http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/deque/deque/erase/ (section "Complexity") states: Linear on the number of elements erased (destructions). Plus, depending on the particular library implemention, up to an additional linear time on the number of elements between position and one of the ends of the deque. So yes, depending on the particular implementation we are both right! :) Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 15):

Even if there is an accepted answer, the normal C++ way is to use provided algorithms. In this case it should be [std::rotate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate)

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator> // for std::advance


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    std::vector<int> v = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    std::cout << "Before: ";
    for (auto element : v)
        std::cout << element << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;

    // edit starts here
    auto first=v.begin();
    auto nfirst=first;
    std::advance(nfirst, 4); // Iterator of first element to move to front
    auto last=nfirst;
    std::advance(last, 1); // 1 is element count for moving to front

    std::rotate(first, nfirst, last);
    // edit ends here

    std::cout << "After: ";
    for (auto element : v)
        std::cout << element << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

*Edit:*
after discussion with Luc Touraille I saw room for improvement. Now the solution uses `std::advance` for iterator manipulation. So it should work with forward iterators which are the requirement for `std::rotate`.

Comment: Hah, forgot about `std::rotate`, makes my own answer pretty useless. Still I would add the argument of `std::vector` being a far better choice than `std::list` in practice and big-O being quite meaningless at all into this excellent answer, too. This doesn't just make your answer the best choice regarding correctness and conciseness, but also most likely regarding perfomance.

Comment: @ChristianRau not to forget it documents what it does.

Comment: Both of your approaches are still better than swapping.

Comment: @JanHerrmann: I took the liberty of adding a generic version of your solution, feel free to rollback if you disagree with my edit.

Comment: @LucTouraille Hmmm. I think std::rotate *is* the generic version the rest is example. Your code does something like move *one* value to front. Of course this is the answer for this particular question but not very gerneric (limitation to std::vector<int>, one element). In addition it creates a name for a special case where std::rotate is used for implementation. For special purposes it might be good but I think in this context it's not. But thanks for your feedback it made me think about when to make things more generic.

Comment: @LucTouraille A generic solution would have completely used iterators instead of a particular container with a particular element type and a particular index type. Without those it isn't generic enough to justify its mentioning as a *"generic solution"* in addition to the already given example (though the general idea of providing such is a good one).

Comment: @ChristianRau and @JanHerrman: Fair points, notably about genericity (my proposition was far too restrictive). However, I still think this particular use of `rotate` deserves a function on its own, not only because a well-chosen name can clarify the purpose (I honestly need to look twice at a `rotate` call to figure what it does), but also to avoid silly mistakes in `rotate` arguments.

Answer (score 3):

Seriously, I have strong doubt that O(n) is really a problem in your actual code. There are much better reasons to use a `std::vector` instead of a `std::list`, like better memory locality and less memory overhead, than just big-O. But you may still optimize the standard approach (which requires `dst` to be before `src`, though)

```
std::vector<int>::iterator src = ..., dst = ...;
...
auto tmp = std::move(*src);
vec.erase(src);
vec.insert(dst, std::move(tmp));
```

a bit by turning both O(n) traversals (one to left-shift in the `erase` and one to right-shift in the `insert`) into just a single (maybe even smaller) one:

```
auto tmp = std::move(*src);
for(auto iter=src; iter!=dst; --iter)
    *iter = std::move(*std::prev(iter));
*dst = std::move(tmp);
```

**EDIT:** Though note that my above code snippet does nothing else than needlessly replicate `std::rotate` as proposed by *Jan* in his answer.

Comment: also erasing `src`, probably invalidates `dst`.

Comment: @user1095108 Only if `dst` is *after* `src`, which is to be excluded anyway. But thansk for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to the excellent answer provided by @JanHerrmann, here is a generic function for moving an element in a range:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

// Moves the element src before dst, maintaining the order of other values
template <typename RandomAccessIt>
void moveElement(RandomAccessIt src, RandomAccessIt dst)
{ 
    if (dst == src)
    {
        return;
    }
    if (dst < src)
    { 
        std::rotate(dst, src, src + 1);
    }
    else
    { 
        std::rotate(src, src + 1, dst);
    }
}

void printVector(const std::vector<int> &v)
{
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main() {

    std::vector<int> v = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    printVector(v); // 0 1 2 3 4 5

    moveElement(v.begin() + 4, v.begin());
    printVector(v); // 4 0 1 2 3 5

    moveElement(v.begin() + 2, v.begin() + 2);
    printVector(v); // 4 0 1 2 3 5

    moveElement(v.begin() + 2, v.begin() + 3);
    printVector(v); // 4 0 1 2 3 5

    moveElement(v.begin() + 2, v.end());
    printVector(v); // 4 0 2 3 5 1
}
```

Comment: Too bad there isn't a resonable `<` for non-random access iterators. I first thought about checking the sign of `std::distance`, but that already requires proper order and is always positive.

Comment: Maybe one could implement a signed `distance` that repeatedly increments and decrements to get a generalized `<`. Having this work for `ForwardIt`s would be really great (though that would probably be beyond the scope of this answer).

Comment: @ChristianRau: A signed `distance` would necessitate an additional parameter: the end of the range that contains the two iterators. Otherwise, you would have no way of knowing when you should stop advancing the first one and "roll back" to start advancing the second. Moreover, this would only work with `ForwardIterator`s and not `InputIterator`s (which are not guaranteed to support multipass), unlike the actual `distance`. Not sure it would be worth the trouble :)!

Comment: There is no need for an additional end, you just increment and decrement alternately (not the same iterator, of course, but copies of it) until you reach the goal on one side (would be O(2n), though). Of course you might iterate till eternity if it isn't reachable on either side, but so would the existing `std::distance` anyway. The problem with `InputIt`s is true, yet using the original `std::distance` (that works on `InputIt`s) and afterwards trying to use the iterators again isn't going to work either, so I would argue the relevance of an `InputIt`-`distance` in practice anyway.

Comment: @ChristianRau: If you decrement the iterators, then you restrict your function to BidirectionalIterators. More importantly, without a bound, the function will most of the time have undefined behavior, because it will often end up calling the operator++ on the end of a sequence (or operator-- on the beginning), which is U.B..